# Showing progress while chart is loading javafx

Tags: javafx, progress-indicator

I'm writing a program in javafx where different charts are being shown. The chart values are based on data collected from a database. Since I have to first collect the data from the database and then do som further calculations in the code some of the charts take some time to load. I would like a progress indicator to show the progress of the chart loading. Before the chart is shown the user selects what kind of chart he/she wants and then clicks a 'Go' button to view the chart. Before the button is clicked the progress indicator looks like this and works perfectly fine:

[image: Progress indicator]

When the user clicks the 'Go' button the chart starts loading and I would like the progress indicator  to show the loading progress in percent. The problem is that as soon as the chart starts loading the progress indicator freezes. All changes that I try to do to the progress bar (and the text below it) will not be done until the entire chart is fully loaded, which kind of ruins the whole purpose of the progress indicator.

Is there any way to make the progress indicator change WHILE the chart is loading?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a different thread for doing the background task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in a different `Thread` from a `Task`, update the progress and bind the progress property to the progress of the `Task`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    Button btn = new Button("Go");
    VBox root = new VBox(10, btn, progressIndicator);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Task<LineChart> task = new Task<LineChart>() {

            @Override
            protected LineChart call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        // do some work
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    updateProgress(10 * i, 100);
                }
                updateProgress(100, 100);

                return new LineChart(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
            }

        };
        progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
            // handle successful completion of task on application thread
            root.getChildren().set(root.getChildren().indexOf(progressIndicator), task.getValue());
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One question: I have different methods for creating different charts. When the 'Go' button is clicked the program checks what chart the user has selected and then calls the method for creating that chart. If the user, for example, has chosen bubble chart the createBubbleChart() method is called. Where can I call these different methods in your code example for the progress to be connected to the loading of that chart?

Comment: @ekstroom Your best options here seem to be either using the strategy or the factory pattern (the factory would create the `Task` creating the chart). Both the strategy or the factory could be used as items for a `ComboBox` or something like this...